# Postgresql - DB listing few DBs twice in the instance

Tags: postgresql

when I do \l+ in the postgres instance, I can see a few database twice.

Something like

```
 foo            | postgres  | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |                       | 584 MB  | pg_default |

 foo            | postgres  | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |                       | 584 MB  | pg_default |

 bar            | postgres  | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |                       | 594 MB  | pg_default |

 bar            | postgres  | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |                       | 594 MB  | pg_default |
```

I am able to connect to both databases "foo" and "bar" without issues. Locally and using connection string.

Will there be any issues with having the databases listed more than once? 
How can I remove the duplicate entry from the postgres server?

Please suggest.

Comment: Maybe they have some leading or trailing whitespaces. What does `select concat('>', datname, '<') from pg_database` show you?

Comment: This seem like some kind of corruption.  What does `select * from pg_catalog.pg_tablespace` show?  What does `\l` without the plus sign show?